# FBRequestConnection startForCustomAudienceThirdPartyID:nil works on simulator, not on device

Tags: objective-c, ios6, objective-c-blocks, facebook-ios-sdk

Using FB SDK 3.6, I am attempting to capture FB User IDs and save to Parse datastore in the cloud to build a custom audience to market to. My call is as follows:

```
 [FBRequestConnection startForCustomAudienceThirdPartyID:nil
               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
               NSString *uid = error ? nil : [result objectForKey:@"custom_audience_third_party_id"];

          if ([uid length] > 0) {
              PFObject *newInstall = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewInstalls"];
              [newInstall setObject:uid forKey:@"FacebookUID"];
              [newInstall saveEventually];  //saves whenever user is online
                                          }
                                 }];
```

It works beautifully on the simulator (v6.1), but when I run on the device (iPhone 5, v6.1.2) it makes the call, but the completion handler never runs. Any suggestions?

Comment: having same problem. did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was 'Limit Ad Tracking' being enabled in iOS Settings that caused the completionHandler to never be called. Turning that off made it work for me.